# Changing protocol without changing state or passing old state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, https

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function stateChangeStart(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams)


var replace = $location.absUrl().replace('http', 'https');
$window.location.href = replace;
$state.params = fromState; //That line of course not working
```

I have tried that one but as I expected it did not work. How to achive that I can pass old state after changing the url.

Comment: setting the location reloads the page so the line after it is not going to run.

Comment: @epascarello thats what I expected and I know it is not working. I am asking is there any way to change protocol without refresh ?

Comment: Changing protocols is going to be an issue. I think `replaceState` needs to be in same protocol.

Comment: @epascarello I may put state to cookie at that time after protocol changed I can get the state from the cookie then protect the state. What you think about it ?